# Why does calling this virtual function in C++ result in a 'missing symbol' error from the base class?

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

I have a virtual class which is defined by:

```
  template<typename TId, typename TValue>
  class Resource {
    private:

      /// Next item in the chain
      unique_ptr<Resource<TId, TValue>> data;

    protected:

      /// The id this value
      TId id;

      /// The value on this value
      TValue value;

    public:

      /// Create a new instance and assign the values to it
      Resource(TId id, TValue value) {
        this->id = id;
        this->value = value;
      }

      /// Destructor
      virtual ~Resource() {
      }

      /// Safely clone a new instance of this
      virtual Resource<TId, TValue> *Clone();

      ... other stuff removed for brevity ...

      /// Create a new resource chain with a custom filter
      Option<Resource<TId, TValue>*> Filter(std::function< bool(Resource<TId, TValue>*) > filter) {
        auto iter = this->Iter<Resource<TId, TValue>>(filter);
        if (iter.Any()) {
          auto index = 0;
          auto root = (*iter.First())->Clone();
          iter.Each([&] (Resource<TId, TValue>* r) {
            if (index != 0) {
              root->Push(r->Clone());
            }
            ++index;
          });
          return Some<Resource<TId, TValue>*>(root);
        }
        return None<Resource<TId, TValue>*>();
      }
  };
```

I've implemented this trivially in a test, as:

```
enum RType {
  ThingOne = 1,
  ThingTwo = 2
};

class RValue : public Resource<RType, i32> {
  public:
    RValue(int value) : Resource(ThingOne, value) {
    }
    ~RValue() {
    }
    Resource<RType, i32>* Clone() {
      return new RValue(this->value);
    }
};
```

NB. Notice the usage of Clone:

```
root->Push(r->Clone());
```

However, on compile I get:

```
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test-resource.dir/tests/test-resource.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable tests/test-resource
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "npp::Resource<RType, int>::Clone()", referenced from:
      vtable for npp::Resource<RType, int> in test-resource.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [tests/test-resource] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test-resource.dir/all] Error 2
```

The compiler is clang, the platform is OSX.

What's going on?

Why is the implementation in the derived class not automatically being resolved when the function is called?

Is it because this is a templated method?

The full code can be found in this gist, for reference: https://gist.github.com/shadowmint/d49650668e9a74c324a1

Comment: In the future, please make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something with minimal code that we can paste and try straight away.

Comment: What on earth is a "virtual class"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to implement a virtual member function of a base class, you have to declare it pure virtual:

```
  //                                     vvv-- here
  virtual Resource<TId, TValue> *Clone() = 0;
```

Otherwise the linker will search for the function you declared but didn't implement when it's generating the virtual function table for the base class (you can see that in the error message you get).

Note that declaring a pure virtual member function in it will make a class abstract.